# PyQGIS - Creating Pie Chart

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3, diagram

I am trying to add a pie chart which summarizes data within each polygon based on two attributes fields ("P_Jet_2007" and "R_Jet_2007"). However, my script (see below) only produces an empty pie chart for each polgyon.

Please can anyone advise on what I am missing from my script?

```
uri = 'C:\PyQGis\P_Wood_Updated.shp'
lyr = iface.addVectorLayer(uri, '', 'ogr')

categories = [u'P_Jet_2007', u'R_Jet_2007']

colors = ['#3727fa', '#6810ff']
qcolors = []
for c in colors:
    qcolors.append(QColor(c))

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

diagram = QgsPieDiagram()

ds = QgsDiagramSettings()

ds.font = QFont ("Helvetica", 12)
ds.transparency = 0
ds.categoryColors = qcolors
ds.categoryAttributes = categories
ds.size = QSizeF (100.0, 100.0)
ds.sizeType = 0
ds.labelPlacementMethod = 1
ds.scaleByårea = True
ds.minimumSize = 0
ds.BackgroundColor = QColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
ds.PenColor = QColor(100, 100, 100, 0)
ds.penWidth = 0



dr = QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer()

dr.setLowerValue(0.0)
dr.setLowerSize(QSizeF(0.0, 0.0))
dr.setUpperValue(2000000)
dr.setUpperSize(QSizeF(1000, 1000))
dr.setClassificationField("Tot_Jet") # Attributed used to control size of pie chart



dr.setDiagram(diagram)

lyr.setDiagramRenderer(dr) 

dls = QgsDiagramLayerSettings()
dls.dist = 0
dls.priority = 0
dls.xPosColumn = -1
dls.yPosColumn = -1
dls.placement = 0
lyr.setDiagramLayerSettings(dls)

label_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
lyr.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label_settings))
lyr.setLabelsEnabled(True)
lyr.triggerRepaint

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My strategy, in this case, is to develop a simpler but functional code (with default values for some settings; other are mandatories). Later, you can add the lines you want for improving your settings. So, in a vector layer (polygon8) in one of my folders, I created 'P_Jet_2007' and 'R_Jet_2007' fields with arbitrary values.

Simplified code is as follows. Observe that I changed your list notation for a more functional dictionary.

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

diagram = QgsPieDiagram()

ds = QgsDiagramSettings()

dColors = {'P_Jet_2007': QColor("#3727fa"),
           'R_Jet_2007': QColor("#6810ff")}
ds.categoryColors = dColors.values()
ds.categoryAttributes = dColors.keys()
ds.categoryLabels = ds.categoryAttributes

dr = QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer()
dr.setUpperValue(100)  # Here you should set the maximum value of both attributes
dr.setUpperSize(QSizeF(10, 10))
dr.setClassificationField('R_Jet_2007')
dr.setDiagram(diagram)
dr.setDiagramSettings(ds)

# Set diagram layer settings:
lyr.setDiagramRenderer(dr)
dls = QgsDiagramLayerSettings()

lyr.setDiagramLayerSettings(dls)
lyr.triggerRepaint()
```

After running above code with **polygon8** layer, I got following result:

[image]

There were produced pie charts associated to each polygon features (I would use other colors!).

So, with 'setUpperValue(20)' for renderer and 'cyan' and 'red' colors:

[image]